# CMake Include third party header for a non cmake library

Tags: c++, cmake

I have a project set up like so:

```
project
  CMakeLists.txt
  src
    CMakeLists.txt
    Mylib.cpp
  thirdparty
    somelib
      include
        header.h
```

I am trying to include header.h inside my code with `#include "header.h"` however  the preprocessor cannot find the header.

I have tried adding the third party include directory using `target_include_directories` in the src CMakeLists.txt, however that does not help. I have tried both `thirdparty/somelib/include` and `../thirdparty/somelib/include` for the path.

How do I properly get the header on the include path?

Comment: It's handy to use the top-level dir of the project tree (aka root) as in `target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/somelib/include)`. If that works, and you're also installing your target, you might want to adjust that with generator expressions, but let's take it one step at a time.

Comment: That worked- I had tried the same thing but had marked the included dir as PRIVATE and included it in my public header which obviously didnt work! Thanks!

Comment: good, I'll convert it to an answer.

Comment: You can add your thirdparty library to your project as a header-only library.  Here's a thorough example: http://mariobadr.com/creating-a-header-only-library-with-cmake.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Converting my comment to an answer and further elaborating some details*

It's handy to use the top-level directory (i.e. root dir) of a project tree, which also has the advantage of shielding you from any locations changes that might take place on the dependent targets

```
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/somelib/include)
```

Make sure to adjust visibility as required (see [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_include_directories.html)). Moreover, if you are planning to install your targets you should adjust the location of the installed headers differently from those used during a build (especially from the user-facing headers of your API), using generator expressions like this

```
target_include_directories(foo PUBLIC
  $<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/thiirdpart/somelib/include/>
  $<INSTALL_INTERFACE:include/thirdparty/somelib/include>  # or whichever structure you choose
)
```